# How do I invoke many thunderbolts in a certain region?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In *Minecraft* 1.12, I'm trying to get a certain region to be hit by constant thunder. I was trying to use this command:

```
/summon minecraft:lightning_bolt 494 33 598 [dx=5,dy=5,dz=5]
```

but it just hits a single block and that's not what I want. Is there a way to do what I want?

[image: Lightning bolts only hitting a single block]

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would achieve this effect. There is a command called /spreadplayers which teleports the specified entity or more entities to a random block within a specified range. Keep in mind that the command teleports the armor stand to the top-most block of the randomly selected spot.

simply summon an armor stand in the center of the area where you want the lightning to strike: `/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["c"],Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1}`

and summon one more armor stand to act as the lightning point:
`/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["lp"],Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1}`

and then you will need a repeating command block (set to always active) running this command:`/execute @e[tag=c] ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~ ~ 10 11 false @e[tag=lp]`
the first number is the desired spread distance and the second one is max distance.

once you activate this command block, you should see the armor stand flying all over the place. Now attach a chain command block to the repeating command block (also set to always active) and paste this in: `/execute @e[tag=lp] ~ ~ ~ summon minecraft:lightning_bolt ~ ~ ~`

tested on 1.12.2,
this is what your command block layout should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the dx, dy, and dz going to the exact spot, i think the d either stands for diameter or distance otherwise, think of it like geometry with the command block as the point you are going away from and where the x y and z is the length of each side of the triangle and then filling in the area, x goes to y and y goes to z and z goes to x and x goes back to the command block. The area of the triangle, again, gets filled in, by having all of them the same number you basically made the area equal to 0 set them each in different numbers e.g. dx=1,dy=2,dz=3

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there is no point in dy = 5;  Lightning will always strike the furthest unobstructed downward place possible.

The actual problem, though, if that you’re relying on dx, dz, and dy to summon lightning everywhere, which means that you are trying to use NBT tags to summon multiple entities at once, while most commands can only summon one at a time.

the only way you would be able to do this is to randomize where they spawned, which would create a relatively even spread.

To fix this, make 25 chain command blocks that each summon lightning in on one of the blocks.

Comment: dx etc. constrain an entity selection to a certain space, they have nothing to do with randomness (or summoning even). And you can summon lightning with commands at any height you want. Your last paragraph is probably the closest to what the asker wants, but the rest is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

Lightning is a thing that hits a certain point, just like in real life. I don't even know how a volume-filling lightning would look like, but it is definitely not possible, neither in Minecraft, nor in real life.

(Also, you're mixing command syntax for selecting entities, NBT and summon commands. You can't just invent any syntax you want and expect it to work, the game can't read your mind.)

Comment: This is simply untrue. Lightning’s damage, though, ‘snaps’ to the nearest entity in a certain area. The visuals, though, stay the same.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it just damages everything in a certain radius (not spherical).

Comment: Fabian Röling I said a certain area, which does not necessarily mean spherical. Also, according to the wiki, is multiple entities in the **area** of the strike, it will choose at random. Wiki Link: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Thunderstorm#Effects_on_mobs                                    From the wiki:  Then if there are any living entities that can see the sky in a 3×3×h region from 3 below the target block up to the world height, one such entity is selected at random

Comment: @brododragon That is indeed something I didn't know yet, but it's also irrelevant in this case, because we're talking about command summoned lightnings. Those always appear exactly at the position you summon them, no matter if there are blocks above or below or entities nearby.

Comment: Yes, but in your answer you said lightning always strikes in certain places

Comment: It does. Or have you ever seen lightning hit an entire wide area at once?

Comment: I thought you meant designated places that never change. And, well duh, just summon more lightning.

Comment: Just do a repeating command block set to always active and type out: ```summon lightning```

Comment: No, that was already what the asker did wrong.